# How to detect if the outer frame is already loaded in single-page app?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, iis, single-page-application

I'm creating a single-page web app that has 3 parts:

- A header
- A sidebar for navigation
- An i-frame to show the main page content

The header and sidebar should never reload after the first page load - only the i-frame. I'm using the History API (i.e. pushstate) to handle history and navigation.

The problem I'm having is if someone types in a url directly to any page in the site, I want to load the header and sidebar and then load the page they went to in the i-frame. If they're already on the page and they click a link to a different page, I only want it to load the new page in the i-frame. I'd like to do this without messing up the navigation history as well.

How do I detect this and load the content appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

In the iframe you would use a little piece of Javascript looking at [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent) and [window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) like this:

*Javascript in iframe*

```
if (window.parent == window.top) {
  // user loaded the iframe, go to parent 
  window.location = "<your parent url>" + "?iframe=" + window.location;
}
```

Then in the parent load the iframe that is indicated by `$_GET['inframe']`:

*PHP in parent*

```
if (isset($_GET['inframe']) {
   loadIframe($_GET['inframe']);
}
```

where I made up a `loadIframe()` function, since you didn't provide any code, so you have to replace that with your own.

For security reasons you may want to filter the input with [filter_input()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php):

*PHP in parent*

```
if (isset($_GET['inframe']) {
   loadIframe(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'inframe'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
}
```

And perform further checks. This way you can prevent people from using the `iframe` parameter to inject something malicious in your code, or from loading just any iframe they please.

Instead of an iframe you could use AJAX to load content, and avoid this problem altogether. An iframe however allows for a more traditional way of loading content.